# Problem with CommunityGraphPlot and facebook

Tags: graphs-and-networks, social-media

When I do this:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"], 
 CommunityLabels -> {"Online friends", "High school\n Local area friends", "Family"}]
```

then I see "f Sign into facebook" and the browser opens up.

After that an error message page appears (the page cannot open the link) and I cannot login into facebook.

What could be the error?

Comment: This functionality is very buggy, I'd contact Technical support

Comment: Please always show a *minimal* example.  Is this related to `SocialMediaData` or to `CommunityGraphPlot`?

Comment: That said, Facebook has restricted its API 2 years ago, and it is not longer possible to get your full friend network, either with Mathematica or any other tool. http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2015/04/15/wolframalpha-personal-analytics-for-facebook-last-chance-to-analyze-your-friend-network/